# Search and Delete duplicate files with different names

Tags: files, duplicate, file-search, file-management

I have a large music collection stored on my hard drive; and browsing through it, I found that I have a lot of duplicate files in some album directories. Usually the duplicates exist alongside the original in the same directory.

Usually the format is **filename.mp3** and duplicate file is **filename 1.mp3**. Sometimes there may be more than one duplicate file, and I have no idea if there are duplicate files across folders (for example duplicates of album directories).

Is there any way I can scan for these duplicate files (for example by comparing filesize, or comparing the entire files to check if they are identical), review the results, and then delete the duplicates? The ones that have a longer name, or the ones that have a more recent modified/created date would usually be the targets of deletion.

Is there a program out there that can do this on Linux?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71351/remove-duplicate-mp3-with-different-name-size-and-hash

Comment: @VincentNivoliers Thanks, I guess that my question is a duplicate in the end, although I wasn't asking for a program specifically for music files (I just used music as an example) that question does have the answers I need to solve my specific problem.

Comment: I would say that if your files are identical to the bits, with different names, then the question would hold, and I would suggest using a hash program combined with a hash table to propose duplicates. For music collections, this is probably not the case if the equivalent files come from different sources.

Comment: Yes, this was what I meant, music files were just my example, but since my exact scenario does involve music files the other thread probably has a good solution for me already.

Hash program sounds like it might be a good solution independent of filetypes, know any?

Comment: See also [Find duplicate files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71176/find-duplicate-files)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is such a program, and it's called `rdfind`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   rdfind [ options ] directory1 | file1 [ directory2 | file2 ] ...

DESCRIPTION
   rdfind  finds duplicate files across and/or within several directories.
   It calculates checksum only if necessary.  rdfind  runs  in  O(Nlog(N))
   time with N being the number of files.

   If  two  (or  more) equal files are found, the program decides which of
   them is the original and the rest are considered  duplicates.  This  is
   done  by  ranking  the  files  to each other and deciding which has the
   highest rank. See section RANKING for details.
```

It can delete the duplicates, or replace them with symbolic or hard links.

Comment: I'm trying this program out now.

Comment: This worked pretty well, **rdfind /mnt/stash/music** told me a total of 1 GB could be cleared up, and created a results.txt file to list all the duplicates. **rdfind -deleteduplicates true /mnt/stash/music** then deleted 2104 duplicate files for me. Thanks!

This program was very high performance, it took only a minute to initially scan through my 200+GB music folder and only a few seconds to delete the duplicate files on it's second run. It would have been nice if it would also delete empty folders though.

Comment: didn't work for me (`command not found`) but the other answer did

Comment: @ashleedawg - "command not found" suggests you don't have `rdfind` installed.  I thought that too obvious to point out.

Answer (score 13):

Hmmph. I just developed a one-liner to list all duplicates, for a
question that turned out to be a duplicate of this. How meta. Well,
shame to waste it, so I'll post it, though `rdfind` sounds like a better
solution.

This at least has the advantage of being the "real" Unix way to do it ;)

```
find -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -Dw 32
```

Breaking the pipeline down:

`find -name '*.mp3' -print0` finds all mp3 files in the subtree starting
at the current directory, printing the names NUL-separated.

`xargs -0 md5sum` reads the NUL-separated list and computes a checksum
on each file.

You know what `sort` does.

`uniq -Dw 32` compares the first 32 characters of the sorted lines and
prints only the ones that have the same hash.

So you end up with a list of all duplicates. You can then whittle that
down manually to the ones you want to delete, remove the hashes, and
pipe the list to `rm`.

Comment: For the record, this is what I was originally hoping to see as an answer :P A one liner without the need to download any extra software (not that I have anything against that, I just like being "clean") Then again rdfind has less legwork, manually sorting out and removing files with matching checksums is a bit of work, ideally it should be done automatically by say deleting all files with the same checksum save for the one with the shortest filename.

Comment: Nice one-liner. One of the things that `rdfind` does better is to check file sizes first in order to exclude unique files from the list

Answer (score 4):

I'm glad you got the job done with `rdfind`.

Next time you could also consider [`rmlint`](http://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).  It's extremely fast and offers a few different [options](http://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#original-detection-selection) to help determine which file is the original in each set of duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I did not like rdfind's approach to finding the originals, it's happened that files I would have considered the duplicate were not the ones deleted (i.e. the original was deleted) it doesn't really bother me though, but if I was OCD...

Answer (score 2):

I'd be thinking of using Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use Digest::SHA qw ( sha1_hex );

my %seen;

sub find_dupes {
    next if -d;
    local $/;
    open( my $input, "<", $File::Find::name ) or warn $!;
    my $sha1sum = sha1_hex(<$input>);
    close($input);
    if ( $seen{$sha1sum} ) {
        print "$File::Find::name is probably a dupe of $seen{$sha1sum} - both have $sha1sum\n";
    }
    $seen{$sha1sum} = $File::Find::name;
}

find( \&find_dupes, "/path/to/search", "/another/path/to/search" );
```